# Rspec: expect file to exist with wildcard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm testing with Rspec whether a file has been saved. I can guarantee that it has, like in Finder, etc., but my test fails:

```
it 'saved a low resolution file' do
  expect(File).to exist("#{Rails.root}/public/files/low_resolution_#{id}_*")
end
```

Can I not use wildcards there? What am I missing?

Comment: A wildcard is not a file... And the test is brittle, as it does not guarantee the exact file you target to exist. How about testing with the actual file name?

Comment: In short, because it's complicated. The wildcard here only ignores like an MD5 string at the end of the file, and transferring that in this application is probably more work than it's worth.

Comment: As your test suite grows, that can get hard to debug. The solution from @fl00r works, but the test remains brittle. The kind of problem you can get is when you'll add tests that also expect something on these files. Please just keep in mind that there seems to be side-effects to this test (well, it also depends on what the suite does around).

Comment: As an alternative, you could try the construct with `allow(...).to_receive(...).and_return(...)` to eliminate side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
low_res = Dir["#{Rails.root}/public/files/low_resolution_#{id}_*"]
expect(low_res).should_not be_empty
```